# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite passthrough working, ending up with 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I ran into a problem that I don't quite understand. I'm not too unfamiliar with mod_rewrite, but I can't find nor fix the problem here.

My aim is to serve all requests for files that end with php without the `.php` ending, so that e.g. `example.com/kontakt` is internally redirected to `kontakt.php`.

If `example.com/kontakt.php` is requested and exists, it shall be rewritten (with a 301) to `example.com/kontakt`.

I have a vHost configured as follows: (actual domain name is not example.com)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

    <Directory /var/www/html/site>
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace5
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The increased log level is due to my debugging.

`/var/www/html/site/.htaccess` has the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

mod_rewrite is loaded and verified to run.
Now, in my docroot, there are various files that end in `.php` and should therefore be rewritten.

One of those is `kontakt.php`. But when I access it as `{host}/kontakt`, the log gives me the following:

```
[Sun Apr 30 00:00:00.000000 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 11111] mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.0.0.1:11111] 10.0.0.2 - - [hostname/sid#7f024bfd5030][rid#7f024bf980a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/site/] pass through /var/www/html/site/kontakt.php
```

which tells me the rewrite was successful and it's trying to pass the request through to `kontakt.php`, but I end up with a HTTP 404 Not found.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the rule affects only a path with ".php" and it wont work since the 2nd cond checks for existence a file with ".php.php"

Comment: I am aware that this affects only pages with `.php`, this was my aim. I edited the question to be more specific. The second cond checks for files with .php.php when you request `example.com/kontakt.php`, and therefore fails, thats true. But that shouldn't matter when I request `example.com/kontakt`, should it?

Comment: `kontakt` is never matches the `(.*)\.php$` thus it can't be rewritten with this rule. Hiding an extention is pretty trivial and searchable task. My suggestion is: 1. check raw http request for the ".php" and redirect it `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\s(\S*)\.php[\?\s]"` \n `RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]` . 2. internal rewrite to a real path `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` \n `RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" -f` \n `RewriteRule "!\.php$" "%{REQUEST_URI}.php" [L]`

Comment: Okay, thats a bit embarassing, that I didn't see that one. Thanks @Deadooshka!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @deadooshka pointed out, my rules never matched the request without PHP, so I implemented the proposed solution of

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "\s(\S*)\.php[\?\s]"
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" -f
RewriteRule "!\.php$" "%{REQUEST_URI}.php" [L]
```

which works flawlessly. Thanks a lot!